# Что означает установление соединения в компьютерных сетях?

Tags: сеть

Установление соединения означает, что клиент и сервер договорились о каком то формате передачи данных, например tcp? Вопрос банальный, но интересно понять суть.

Comment: Ну обычно всё-таки да. Того, что сервер просто "видим" недостаточно. Именно установлено соединение определённого формата, грубо говоря клиент послал некое приветствие и получил от сервера ответ определённого образца. Хотя лучше смотреть описание конкретных протоколов, где-то может и просто наличие коннекта на определённый IP адрес и порт уже означать установление соединения, даже до начала обмена любезностями.

Comment: @CrazyElf посмотрите комменты к следующему ответу ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, правильным ответом было бы ответить вопросом на вопрос "а на каком уровне модели OSI?"

Но по традиции когда нет уточнений -  то обычно речь идёт о tcp/ip - соединениях.

А это не тот случай, когда речь **не** идёт о формате: tcp/ip слишком низкоуровневый, это все равно, что говорить, "если программа записывает файл-означает ли это, что это файл в каком то формате?". В общем случае-нет.

Но, *как правило*, клиенты пытаются коннектиться только к тем серверам, с которыми у них совместим формат обмена данными.

В комментариях хорошо уточнили (задав вопрос): "**Возможность соединения, по видимому всё таки обусловлена больше наличием канала связи, нежели протоколом?**"

В общем - получается, что соединение может быть, клиент и сервер пытаются обмениваться данными, но при этом выводят сплошные ошибки. Это пример того, что соединение есть, но о формате они не договорились.

И еще одно уточнение: "договорились о каком то формате передачи данных, например tcp". *Это не совсем верно.*

Точнее, всё зависит от того, какое значение Вы вкладываете в слово "формат".

С одной стороны, для приложения прикладного уровня tcp (точнее, tcp/ip) tcp-соединение - это "труба", в которую клиент и сервер могут запихивать байты. На то, что это будут за байты, tcp не накладывает никаких ограничений.

С другой стороны, как написал в коментарии andreymal: "Протокол — это по определению и есть формат передачи. И стек протоколов TCP/IP действительно накладывает определённые ограничения, где и какие байты должны быть (просто это всё происходит внутри ОС и детали реализации протоколов скрыты от прикладных приложений)"

Comment: То есть тот факт, что клиент "щебечит на не понятном серверу языке" означает, что соединения нет?

Comment: Сам факт прохождения данных от одной стороны к другой не означает ли, что соединение между ними есть? Например неанглоговорящий китаец звонит англичанину, который не знает китайского. Они могут пытаться говорить с друг другом, не понимать, но соединение то установлено?

Comment: Возможность соединения, по видимому всё таки обусловлена больше наличием канала связи, нежели протоколом?

Comment: Протокол — это по определению и есть формат передачи. И стек протоколов TCP/IP действительно накладывает определённые ограничения, где и какие байты должны быть (просто это всё происходит внутри ОС и детали реализации протоколов скрыты от прикладных приложений)

Comment: @andreymal - спасибо, очень грамотное уточнение. Сейчас добавлю его к ответу, точнее, заменю им свою безграмотную фразу :-)